# This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'number' and '{ id: number; }' have no overlap

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I was doing a Context of my application and I have this error "This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'number' and '{ id: number; }' have no overlap", I am practicing with typescript but I have neither idea how can i fix that, this is my code.

```
import { Note, NoteState } from "../interfaces/interfaces";

type NoteActions =
    | { type: 'addNote', payload: Note }
    | { type: 'toggleInteresting', payload: { id: number } }
    | { type: 'changeState', payload: string }
    | { type: 'deleteNote', payload: { id: number } }

export const NoteReducer = (state: NoteState, action: NoteActions): NoteState => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'addNote':
            return {
                ...state,
                notes: [...state.notes, action.payload]
            }

        case 'toggleInteresting':
            return {
                ...state,
                notes: state.notes.map(({ ...note }) => {
                    if (note.id === action.payload.id) {
                        note.interesting = !note.interesting;
                    }

                    return note
                })
            }
        case 'changeState':
            return {
                ...state,
                active: action.payload
            }
        case 'deleteNote':
            return {
                ...state,
                ERROR
                <----notes: state.notes.filter(note => note.id != action.payload)--->
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and this is my interface:

```
export interface Note {
    id: number;
    description: string;
    title: string;
    interesting: boolean;
    created: string;
}

export interface NoteState {
    notesCount: number;
    notes: Note[];
    active: any;
}
```

Comment: You probably want `note.id !== action.payload.id` like you have in your `map` under `toggleInteresting`....

Comment: `note.id != action.payload` Left side is a `number`, right side is `{ id: number; }`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I was able to solve it

Answer (score 1):

You defined action `{ type: 'deleteNote', payload: { id: number } }` - here you said that payload should be object containing id.

And here you try to compare payload object with number:
`notes: state.notes.filter(note => note.id != action.payload)`

Take a look at your `'toggleInteresting'` action - you are comparing it correctly:

```
notes: state.notes.map(({ ...note }) => {
  if (note.id === action.payload.id) {
    note.interesting = !note.interesting;
    }

    return note
  })
```

Correct condition should be:
`notes: state.notes.filter(note => note.id != action.payload.id)`

Comment: thanks for the explanation, now the app works